# Entity Framework 1:0..1 relation in mvc 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5

I wanted to create a relation between two of my models to be 1:0..1 but all i got is a 1..* relation:

```
public class MedicalExamination
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime ExecutionDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime AcceptanceDate { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }

    public string Result { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public virtual Visit Visit { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual ExaminationDictionary ExaminationDictionary { get; set; }

}
```

and my second model:

```
public class ExaminationDictionary
{
    [Key]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }


    public virtual MedicalExamination MedicalExamination { get; set; }

}
```

And after i ran it and updated the database i got a relation like this: http://scr.hu/11m6/4eny0
The thing is that i would like it to be 0..1:1 relation. Does anybody know a good solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

A 1-to-1 or 1-to-0or1 relation in Entity Framework is only possible if both tables share the same primary key.

So for example, your MedicalExamination is presumably the principal entity in the relationship. It has an Id column primary key. Your ExaminationDictionary table needs to have an Id column that is its primary.

You then describe the relationship using Fluent API like so:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MedicalExamination>()
    .HasOptional(m=>m.ExaminationDictionary)
    .WithRequiredPrincipal(d=>d.MedicalExamination);
```